# Configure Gitlab CI stages to not run in parallel

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab CI pipeline with multiple stages. By default, the same stage between two jobs will be run in parallel. One of the stages I have is an integration test stage that should only have one running instance at a time since it relies on specific resources being setup and torn down.

Is there a simple way to specify a certain stage should only have one concurrent instance?

Gitlab Enterprise Edition v10.0.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is possible however it's not straightforward. Define a job with a tag:

```
job:
  tags:
    - integration
  script:
    - run intergation tests
```

This will make sure the job runs only on a runner that has a specific tag. Now create a runner with the tag `integration` and concurrency set to 1.

The integration test will run one at a time because there's only one runner who can run them and there's only 1 slot on it.

Comment: That's a reasonable solution. Unfortunately we only have one runner right now so I won't be able to implement it this way. Thanks for your response though!

Comment: @mattherman You can have multiple runners configured on the same instance, just add another section to config.toml.

Comment: @JakubKania won't that lag the machine? Assuming the machine is not scalable (say a Mac Mini).

Comment: @CyberMew not sure what you mean by lag. You can have a global limit on numbers of runners running if you mix this single runner with any others. If you'd much rather have one at a time but spread across many machines that would require more complicated locking mechanism.